# How to check if the ID in an array of objects is the same as the ID in another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects. The first one contain a user's vacation and leave information in the company. The second one contains the leave and vacation types that is entered by the company. Here are my arrays;

USER PERMIT PERIOD ARRAY;

```
permitPeriod: [
   {
      "id":"681ccdfa-ffa9-444f-85d0-cd52dd3fd6aa",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"01 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"03 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:42:03.948+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   },
   {
      "id":"cd7fa524-ee24-4a03-b654-4a7a8ad78fec",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"27 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"31 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:22:40.360+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   }
]
```

And here is the list of Leave Types;

```
leaveTypes:[
   {
      "id":"034cee3b-59ef-4b02-99c1-ec69fc28c6bb",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Yearly Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Reported Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"5d5f46d0-48b2-4bf8-b400-93df1b928cd9",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Sunday",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6790f3df-b7c8-4f59-ad5c-6059aa3bcf59",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Birth Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6eb384d7-3bde-49a2-abf3-0ce61f6679f2",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Unpaid Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Death Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"a001f535-e919-47bb-93d3-1beb61a93da0",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":0,
      "leaveType":"Bonus Leave",
      "abbreviation":"P",
      "status":true
   },
]
```

Both of these arrays can change at any time. The user can request permission from the system or the company can add or remove leave types in the leaveTypes list. In other words, these two arrays are not in a static variable.

What I want to do is, compare these. Here is my logic;

If the ID of one of the elements in the permitPeriod array is equal to the ID of one of the elements in the leaveTypes arrays, I just need to set a variable named permitPeriod.permitPeriodName for that element to leaveType.leaveType with equal ID. Thus, using the permitPeriodType ID in the user's permission information, I can take the string value of the matched data in the leaveTypes array and display it in the table.

Here is what I've tried;

```
      if (this.leaveTypes != null) {
        for(var i = 0; this.permitPeriod.length; i++){
          for(var j = 0; this.leaveTypes.length; j++){
            if(this.permitPeriod[i].permitPeriodType == this.leaveTypes[j].id){
              this.permitPeriod[i].permitPeriodName = this.leaveTypes[j].leaveType;
            }
          }
        }
```

So basically what I wanted to do is search both arrays, find the common ID in one of the element(s) and equalize the value in one to the other. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Here is the response when I send the request to get the `permitPeriod(s)`

[image]

So there is no `permitPeriodName` that came from response. I need to create and push that variable when it is equal to leaveType.leaveType

Comment: Just map the types by the id so you can do a simple lookup. `const leaveTypesMapped = this.leaveTypes.reduce((o, opt) => { o[opt.permitPeriodType] = opt; return o; }, {});`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was basically correct you just need to change the breakup condition for your loops from
`for(var i = 0; this.permitPeriod.length; i++)`
to
`for(var i = 0; i < this.permitPeriod.length; i++)` and from `for(var j = 0; this.leaveTypes.length; j++)` to `for(var j = 0; j < this.leaveTypes.length; j++)`

```js
const permitPeriod = [
   {
      "id":"681ccdfa-ffa9-444f-85d0-cd52dd3fd6aa",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"01 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"03 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:42:03.948+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   },
   {
      "id":"cd7fa524-ee24-4a03-b654-4a7a8ad78fec",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"27 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"31 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:22:40.360+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   }
];

const leaveTypes = [
   {
      "id":"034cee3b-59ef-4b02-99c1-ec69fc28c6bb",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Yearly Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Reported Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"5d5f46d0-48b2-4bf8-b400-93df1b928cd9",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Sunday",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6790f3df-b7c8-4f59-ad5c-6059aa3bcf59",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Birth Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6eb384d7-3bde-49a2-abf3-0ce61f6679f2",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Unpaid Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Death Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"a001f535-e919-47bb-93d3-1beb61a93da0",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":0,
      "leaveType":"Bonus Leave",
      "abbreviation":"P",
      "status":true
   },
];


if (leaveTypes != null) {
  for(var i = 0; i < permitPeriod.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < leaveTypes.length; j++){
      if(permitPeriod[i].permitPeriodType == leaveTypes[j].id){
        permitPeriod[i].permitPeriodName = leaveTypes[j].leaveType;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(permitPeriod);
```

Comment: Yes you're right my logic was correct after all... But I still need to figure out why there is no permitPeriodName property in my permitPeriod objects... I need them in order to display the leave type names on the table...

Comment: Looking at ur update i guess this is a whole new question please open another Question for that and add the code that returns the response. This has nothing to do with filtering arrays.

Comment: It has something to do with filtering arrays actually... I tried to change value of permitPeriodType which was holding the string of IDs and tried to put leaveType.leaveType it didn't work either. I tried that because it may be related not having the data in the first place from the response. I tried with a property that came from the response but didn't work again.

Answer (score 2):

Array.map with Array.find inside:

```js
const permitPeriod = [
   {
      "id":"681ccdfa-ffa9-444f-85d0-cd52dd3fd6aa",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"01 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"03 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:42:03.948+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   },
   {
      "id":"cd7fa524-ee24-4a03-b654-4a7a8ad78fec",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "userId":"10e8b6c0-5c17-4b75-872f-062d3716d7a7",
      "permissionRightStartDate":"27 July 2022",
      "permissionRightEndDate":"31 July 2022",
      "active":false,
      "permitPeriod":"2",
      "permitPeriodType":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "createdAt":"2022-07-27T12:22:40.360+00:00",
      "state":"Deactivated"
   }
];

const leaveTypes = [
   {
      "id":"034cee3b-59ef-4b02-99c1-ec69fc28c6bb",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Yearly Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"05097d26-f04d-483b-bdd9-fa51dc40046d",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Reported Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"5d5f46d0-48b2-4bf8-b400-93df1b928cd9",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Sunday",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6790f3df-b7c8-4f59-ad5c-6059aa3bcf59",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Birth Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"6eb384d7-3bde-49a2-abf3-0ce61f6679f2",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Unpaid Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"7b987436-ead1-47b6-9ed1-cef2a857f114",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":1,
      "leaveType":"Death Leave",
      "abbreviation":null,
      "status":true
   },
   {
      "id":"a001f535-e919-47bb-93d3-1beb61a93da0",
      "companyId":"535f37cc-97cb-461b-9626-f85dc9e59c10",
      "wageStatus":0,
      "leaveType":"Bonus Leave",
      "abbreviation":"P",
      "status":true
   },
];

const result = permitPeriod.map(pp => {
  const leaveType = leaveTypes.find(lt => lt.id === pp.permitPeriodType);
  if (leaveType) {
    return {...pp, permitPeriodName: leaveType.leaveType};
  }
  return pp;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a great solution but in the end I need to push a new variable called permitPeriodName and it has to be equal to leaveType.leaveType. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the result output has `permitPeriodName` property already.

Comment: Yeah I know I noticed that too but in the console output of the result there is no property named permitPeriodName...

Comment: ??? It's right there in the console.  Are you saying "when I take your code and try to adapt it to my issue, it doesn't produce permitPeriodName properties"?  Does it generate errors?

Comment: I took the code that you suggested, it's working just fine and it gives two objects which is correct but those objects don't include permitPermiodName property. I updated my question and added the response. In the response that I'm given there is no permitPeriodName property, I need to create and push it to my objects so that I can use them. I hope I could explain the problem. Maybe your code is not adding or producing permitPeriodName because there was none in the first place when the date came from the response. I don't think that's the issue but there is a possibility...

Comment: Both resulting objects include the ```permitPeriodName``` property!!! Just run the snippet and look at the output.